# Initializing Direct3D failure in rastertek tutorial

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx-11, direct3d11

so I've started to get familiar with C++ language and DirectX 11.
Mainly because a huge resource to learn from is available.

The tutorial can be found here http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut03.html

The problem is that DirectX 11 Visual studio 2010 programmes don't really work, the initialize process returns false

My problem is fairly simple. It doesn't initialize the Direct3D, no errors just it doesn't get the boolean to be equal to true. Downloading the solution will result to the same.

```
// Initialize the Direct3D object.
result = m_D3D->Initialize(screenWidth, screenHeight, VSYNC_ENABLED, hwnd, FULL_SCREEN, SCREEN_DEPTH, SCREEN_NEAR);
if(!result)
{
    MessageBox(hwnd, L"Could not initialize Direct3D", L"Error", MB_OK);
    return false;
}
```

The whole initialize code is over 100 lines long but it does all the checks you can see in the tutorial page.

I encountered that the drivers can have the problem and found this:
[So there's one thing we can notice, the DDI is 10 instead of 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKlf5.png)

So is this the problem I might have that doesn't let Direct X 11 to run, and how to fix that?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: *"Could it be that I'm missing something really vital?"* - Yes, a [mcve].

Comment: The code can be found in the link and mine is 1:1 with it.
So the tutorial doesn't really mention anything about this problem, it expects that there's no failure. But what causes it?

Comment: The tutorial is certainly not *"minimal"*, and questions around here aren't supposed to link to off-site content, if that is vital to the question.

Comment: Yea no idea how to do that .... alright, I'll let you write a question in my place so I can see and learn from you how to write a minimal question about this exact problem. If you can simply tell that this is incorrect show this in correct way.

Comment: My profile is visible to you. You can look at my questions there if you need inspiration.

Comment: Ironic enough your questions have the same flaws here and there.

Comment: They are still self-contained. That's what matters. Now assume someone invests their time to write a good answer to your question, and then the off-site resource goes offline. That invalidates your question, and the answer along with it. That's what SO tries to prevent by establishing the rules you don't seem to like much. Regardless, those are the rules.

Comment: Yea.... I have no idea how to rewrite the question, so I'll trust you with this task as you see the problems better than I do but I need rather to see how to fix this problem I'm having, that is Direct 3D is not initializing. instead of how to make correct question.

Comment: Asking the right question is your best hope for a solution. See [ask] for help.

Comment: Now it's more or less ok?

Comment: That doesn't help much. We cannot see the code that fails. It's just some C++ class member that returns `false`. Use a debugger to single-step through the code and find out, which D3D-call fails.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually called out specifically in the tutorial:

```
// Set the feature level to DirectX 11.
featureLevel = D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0;
```

> Note that if the user does not have a DirectX 11 video card this function call will fail to create the device and device context. Also if you are testing DirectX 11 functionality yourself and don't have a DirectX 11 video card then you can replace D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE with D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE and DirectX will use your CPU to draw instead of the video card hardware. Note that this runs 1/1000 the speed but it is good for people who don't have DirectX 11 video cards yet on all their machines.

```
// Create the swap chain, Direct3D device, and Direct3D device context.
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, &featureLevel, 1, 
                       D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
if(FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}
```

Since your `dxdiag` shows you have 10.0, you can't use `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` with HARDWARE. Since the rastertek tutorials are a bit dated, they fail to mention that you can use `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0` or `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP` (a software driver that is slower than hardware but much faster than the old reference driver).

See [Direct3D Feature Levels](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels/) and [Anatomy of Direct3D 11 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/02/05/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/).

> The rastertek tutorials are useful, but are old. In particular they use a lot of [deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) content from the [legacy DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). I would recommend that you instead update to a newer version of Visual Studio (perhaps the [Community edition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)) and make use of the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). Once you've mastered that content, you can go back to the rastertek tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I was checking the thing and decided to work with Direct X 10 instead, as speed matters for a PC like mine.

I think I'll update to newer VS when I'll buy a new laptop, It'll mess up my current projects and the flow I'm in right now.

Comment: You do not need to use the DirectX 10 API and you shouldn't. It's deprecated and no new program should use it. The DirectX 11 API actually supports *more* hardware than DirectX 10 and has exactly the same performance or better. The problem is the tutorials you are using which are built assuming you have a ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`` or better video card. The _DirectX Tool Kit_ tutorials will work on Direct3D Feature Level 9.3 or better hardware.

Comment: Can I follow them Code::Blocks or VS2010 as I don't want to fill more memory and spend more time with changing the IDE